# Audio delay when video editing and on virtual machines, but only when using internal audio card with speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, audio-sync

I have got some new hardware for my PC and I have Ubuntu 18.04. I use speakers and the Mobo internal audio card.

With the HW I had before the audio was playing just fine while doing any operations on my computer, but now when I edit `60 FPS 1080p` videos on a video editor (tried Kdenlive, OpenShot, Shotcut) and I reproduce them in the program **the audio is delayed**.

This issue is **NOT** existing when playing those videos on normal video players (tried MVP, SMPlayer and VLC).

I have also noticed that on virtual machines (tried Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 with new kernel 5.4) I get the same issue on **both** video editing software and normal video players.

I also tried to boot the system from a USB live with KDE Neon (latest version `neon-user-20200507-1116.iso`) and the result is the same as my main OS system, so audio is delayed only when editing videos (used Kdenlive here).

The delay does **NOT** exist when I use headphones (with integrated USB card), so the problem is with the speakers and so the integrated Mobo audio card, I guess.

Below you can see the HW info from the `inxi -Fxz` command:

```
System:    Host: USER Kernel: 5.3.0-7648-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.5.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.4.8 
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: Micro-Star model: B450 TOMAHAWK MAX (MS-7C02) v: 1.0 serial: <filter> 
           UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends v: 3.50 date: 11/07/2019 
CPU:       Topology: 6-Core model: AMD Ryzen 5 3600X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 91191 
           Speed: 2148 MHz min/max: 2200/3800 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2148 2: 2299 3: 2293 4: 3266 5: 2403 6: 4195 7: 2280 
           8: 2883 9: 2470 10: 2491 11: 2439 12: 3425 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia v: 440.82 bus ID: 26:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1660/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.82 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: NVIDIA vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 26:00.1 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 28:00.4 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.3.0-7648-generic
```

and also the processor from `alsamixer`:

```
1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                     HD-Audio Generic at 0xf7400000 irq 80

Audio card processor: Realtek ALC892
```

Since it happens even in a clean live OS instance (from live USB iso) what do you suggest to try to fix?

Any idea about the source of the issue and how to fix it?

Thanks